# cannot open /usr/share/apache2/build/config_vars.mk: No such file or directory at /usr/bin/apxs2 line 203

Tags: 16.04, apache2

Please what does this means can someone help

`cannot open /usr/share/apache2/build/config_vars.mk: No such file or directory at /usr/bin/apxs2 line 203.`

Thank you

```
 apt-cache policy apache2-dev
apache2-dev:
  Installed: 2.4.18-2ubuntu3.10
  Candidate: 2.4.18-2ubuntu3.10
  Version table:
 *** 2.4.18-2ubuntu3.10 500
        500 http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.4.18-2ubuntu3 500
        500 http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
```

apache2 -v

```
The program 'apache2' is currently not installed. To run 'apache2' please ask your administrator to install the package 'apache2-bin'


sudo systemctl    status  apache2
● apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: inactive (dead) since to 2019-06-06 01:08:07 EEST; 2min 15s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)

kesä 06 01:08:07 bozz-feedz systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Apache2 web server...
kesä 06 01:08:07 bozz-feedz systemd[1]: Started LSB: Apache2 web server.
```

Comment: Did you try to run `apxs2` or something?  This usually happens when there's a prerequisite somewhere that you don't have, and it LOOKS like it's generated by `apxs2` in this case.

Comment: am getting exactly the same output on running apxs2.  Yeah something is missing, how can i fix it

Answer (score 1):

This file is contained in `apache2-dev` package (see [search results](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=xenial&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=config_vars.mk) on packages.ubuntu.com). So you need to install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2-bin apache2-dev
```

and then retry.

Comment: it's saying I have the latest apacha,  Should i remove it and retry again

Comment: Please add the output of `apt-cache policy apache2-dev` to the question body by [editing](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1148853/edit) it.

Comment: Can you check it now

Comment: It's still having the same problem, i can't even check the version apacha -v. AM USING 16.04

Comment: To be sure please add output of `apt-cache policy apache2-bin`, `apache2 -v`, `which apache2` to the question.

Comment: it's weird, saying the program apache2 currently not installed ... Which apache2 is no result

Comment: So you need to install apache2-bin package first :)

Comment: how do i install this, apacha 2 is suppose to install apache2-bin automatically.... I have been battling this stuff through the entire day.